# Recurrence relation of number of sequences with $0,1$ and $2$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

$d_n$ represents number of sequences of length $n$ made by $0, 1$ and $2$ that don't contain two consecutive 1 or 2. for example $d_2 = 7$ because valid sequences are $\{00,01,02,10,12,20,21\}$. first part of question asks to prove that $d_n = 2d_{n-1} + d_{n-2}$ and second part of question is show that

> $d_n = 1 + 2 {n+1 \choose 2 } + 2^2 {n+1 \choose 4} + 2^3 {n+1 \choose 6} + ...$

I proved the first part but I don't have any idea about second part. can any one give me a hint to solving the second part of problem?

Comment: Try seeing if that given formula is true when $n=2$ (since you know $d_2=7$).  And check that the formula satisfies the recurrence relation.

Comment: Another way is to solve the recurrence relation using the standard method (solve its characteristic equation). Then show that the result you get equals that expression in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$f(n)=\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n+1}{2\ell}\;;$$

you want to prove that $d_n=f(n)$ for all $n\ge 0$. The simplest approach is to prove it by induction on $n$. It’s easy enough to check that $d_0=f(0)$ and $d_1=f(1)$, and since the recurrence is second order, you need both of these in order to get the induction started. For the induction step, let $n>1$, and for your induction hypothesis assume that $d_k=f(k)$ for $0\le k<n$; the induction step will then consist in showing that $d_n=f(n)$. You have

$$\begin{align*}
d_n&=2d_{n-1}+d_{n-2}\\
&=2f(n-1)+f(n-2)\\
&=2\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n}{2\ell}+\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n-1}{2\ell}\\
&=\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^{\ell+1}\binom{n}{2\ell}+\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n-1}{2\ell}
\end{align*}$$

by the induction hypothesis, and you want to show that this is equal to $f(n)$, i.e., that

$$\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n+1}{2\ell}=\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^{\ell+1}\binom{n}{2\ell}+\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n-1}{2\ell}\;.\tag{1}$$

A natural idea is to apply Pascal’s identity a few times to reduce all of the binomial coefficients to the same upper number, $n-1$:

$$\binom{n+1}{2\ell}=\binom{n}{2\ell}+\binom{n}{2\ell-1}=\binom{n-1}{2\ell}+2\binom{n-1}{2\ell-1}+\binom{n-1}{2\ell-2}\;,$$

and

$$\binom{n}{2\ell}=\binom{n-1}{2\ell}+\binom{n-1}{2\ell-1}\;,$$

so $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$\begin{align*}
\color{red}{\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n-1}{2\ell}}&+\color{blue}{2\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n-1}{2\ell-1}}+\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n-1}{2\ell-2}\\
&=\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^{\ell+1}\binom{n-1}{2\ell}+\color{blue}{\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^{\ell+1}\binom{n-1}{2\ell-1}}+\color{red}{\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n-1}{2\ell}}\;,
\end{align*}$$

which simplifies to

$$\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^\ell\binom{n-1}{2\ell-2}=\sum_{\ell\ge 0}2^{\ell+1}\binom{n-1}{2\ell}\;.\tag{2}$$

To complete the induction step, you need only show that $(2)$ is true: we’ve seen that it’s equivalent to $(1)$, which is what you need for the induction step.